# Java foreach loop with two arrays

Tags: java, arrays, loops, arraylist, foreach

I have a simple question, can something like the following possibly be done on Java?

```
ArrayList<String> arr1 = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> arr2 = new ArrayList<String>();

// Processing arrays, filling them with data

for(String str : arr1, arr2) {
    //Do stuff
}
```

Where the intent is to iterate through the first array then the next array.

The best I can figure is to either use separate for loops which makes for redundant coding when the for loops have identical internal code.

Another solution was to make an array of ArrayLists. This makes it easy to fulfil my intent, that is:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> arr = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();

// Initialising arr and populating with data
for(ArrayList<String> tempArr : arr) {
    for(String str : tempArr) {
        //Do stuff
    }
}
```

But this makes for unreadable code. Is there a clean way of doing the latter where I don't lose the names of the separate arrays?

Thanks in advance, Declan

Comment: Why not use a standard for-loop?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not possible, at least with below Java 9. Here is a possible way

```
i1= arr1.iterator();
i2= arr2.iterator();
while(i1.hasNext() && i2.hasNext()) 
{
  
   ToDo1(i1.next());
   ToDo2(i2.next());
}
```

Answer (score 4):

A workaround would be to use `Streams`

```
 Stream.concat(arr1.stream(),arr2.stream()).forEachOrdered(str -> {
   // for loop body
 });
```

Answer (score 2):

You can chain multiple collections together using `Stream.of` and `flatMap` in Java 8 and iterate over sequentially in order passed to `Stream.of`

```
Stream.of(s1, s2 ...).flatMap(s -> s)
```

Example:

```
ArrayList<String> arr1 = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> arr2 = new ArrayList<>();

arr1.add("Hello");
arr2.add("World");

Stream.of(arr1.stream(), arr2.stream()).flatMap(s -> s).forEach(s1 -> {
    System.out.println(s1);
});
```

Code above will print

```
Hello
world
```

Answer (score -2):

Not Possible, Try the below code

```
List<String> arr1=new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> arr2==new ArrayList<String>();
List<ArrayList<String>> arrList=new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
arrList.add(arr1);
arrList.add(arr2);
for(ArrayList<String> strlist : arrList) {
  for(String s:strlist){
      // process array
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply!